# Usage of HttpContext in dotnet core 2.2

Tags: httpcontext

I would like get key from sessions, but the compiler is complaining that the class is static when it is not. Can anyone please help me out?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using LitOnline_V1.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Test{

    public class GetValidateUer{

        public int GetUserValidation(){

            var isValidated = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("isValidated");
            return isValidated;
        }
    }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

`Error  CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'`

Comment: Yes, you cannot access session on the class itself. You need to have access to an instance of the current `HttpContext` when you call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it help

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            MyMethod(HttpContext);

            // Some Code
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
    {
        var host = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}";

        // Some Code
    }
```